# Magento admin block does not appear

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am experiencing very strange issue:

i have a module and it works in magento 1.4.0.0 - 1.7

recently i have someone that this module does not show in backend.

this the xml layout code

```
        <reference name="content">
        <block output="toHtml" type="syncer/adminhtml_mapping" template="wisepricer/mapping.phtml" name="wisepricer.mapping" />
    </reference>
```

another peace of xml layout which goes to head - does appear.

i saw that it finds the block class (if you put die in the block constructor - it works).
But if you put die in the template - nothing. No logging about this.

the path to the template adminhtml/default/default/template/wisepricer/mapping.phtml

any ideas?

thanks

edit:

thanks for the reply guys, here is the additional info:

block declaration in config.xml

```
     <blocks>
        <syncer>
            <class>Wisepricer_Syncer_Block</class>
        </syncer>
    </blocks>
```

part of the block class

```
<?php

/******************************************
*        wisepricer         *
******************************************/

class Wisepricer_Syncer_Block_Adminhtml_Mapping extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{

function __construct() {
   $this->setTemplate("wisepricer/mapping.phtml");
}

public function getHeader(){
    $header = "Wisepricer Mapping";
    return $header;
}
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0"> 
    <adminhtml_syncer_mapping>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type>                                                       <name>wisepricer/prototype17.js</name></action>   
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type>    <name>wisepricer/chosen.proto.js</name></action> 
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>wisepricer/wisepricer.css</stylesheet>    </action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>wisepricer/chosen.css</stylesheet>    </action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type>    <name>wisepricer/chosen.proto.js</name></action>            
        </reference>
       <reference name="content">
            <block output="toHtml" type="syncer/adminhtml_mapping"     template="wisepricer/mapping.phtml" name="wisepricer.mapping" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_syncer_mapping> 
</layout>
```

template

```
    <?php
    $adminobj= new Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template(); 
    $formkey=$adminobj->getFormKey();
    $licenseData=Mage::getModel('wisepricer_syncer/config')->load(1);
?>
    <form id="mapping_form" name="mapping_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/savemapping')?>">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
        <input name="mapping_form[stock]" type="hidden" value="qty" />
     <div class="top_block">
        <div class="top_block_left">
            <div class="inner-cont">
                <a href="http://www.wisepricer.com" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/wisepricer/wp-logo.png'); ?>"/></a>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="top_block_right">
        <button class="wp-save-btn" onclick="return beforeSubmit()"></button>
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="mid_block">
        <div class="mid_block_left">
          <div class="guidelines">
            <div class="guidelines-block">
              <p><?php echo $this->__('Enter your WisePricer license key you received from WisePricer. This will link this store with your WisePricer account.')?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelines-block import-guidelines">
              <p><?php echo $this->__('Choose which products to import to WisePricer.')?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="guidelines-block mapping-guidelines">
              <h4><?php echo $this->__('Wisepricer mapping guidelines:')?></h4>
              <ul>
                <li id="rule1"><?php echo $this->__('If you have <span class="field">UPC</span> or <span class="field">ASIN</span> then fields <span class="field">BRAND</span>,<span class="field">MODEL</span>,<span class="field">MPN</span> are not required.')?></li>
                <li id="rule2"><?php echo $this->__('If you don\'t have <span class="field">UPC</span> or <span class="field">ASIN</span>, then you should have at least one of the following combinations: <span class="field">BRAND+MODEL</span> or <span class="field">BRAND+MPN</span>')?></li>
                <li id="rule3"><?php echo $this->__('You must have either <span class="field">COST</span> or <span class="field">MINPRICE</span> or, you can set fixed rule for <span class="field">MINPRICE</span>')?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->__('<span class="field">NAME</span>, <span class="field">SKU</span>, and <span class="field">PRICE</span> fields are required')?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->__('Other fields are not required, but having them will increase your ability to interact with them within WisePricer(e.g. setting advanced rules, better matching and more)')?></li>
              </ul>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mid_block_right">
            <div class="values-block">
                <div class="license-block">
                    <div class="label-block"><label><?php echo $this->__('Enter your License key')?> <span class="required">*</span></label></div>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $licenseData->getLicensekey()?>" class="input-text required-entry" name="register_form[licensekey]" />
                </div>        
            </div>
            <div class="values-block">
                <div class="license-block import-settings">
                  <div class="values-block-sub b10">
                    <div class="label-block"><label><?php echo $this->__('Import:')?></label></div>
                    <?php echo $this->renderWebsitesSelect($licenseData->getWebsite())?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="values-block-sub b10">
                    <div class="label-block"><label><?php echo $this->__('Product types:')?></label></div>
                    <?php echo $this->renderTypesSelect($licenseData->getProduct_type())?>
                  </div>
                  <div class="values-block-sub b10 check-block">
                        <div class="label-block b0"><label><?php echo $this->__('Do not import out of stock items')?></label></div>
                        <input  type="checkbox" name="register_form[import_outofstock]" <?php echo $this->getImportOutStockSet();?>/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="values-block-sub check-block">
                        <div class="label-block b0"><label><?php echo $this->__('Reprice Configurable')?></label></div>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="register_form[reprice_configurable]" <?php if($licenseData->getReprice_configurable()){ echo 'checked';}?>/>
                        <p class="wptip"><?php echo $this->__('The Configurable product will be assigned to the price of his cheapest child')?></p>
                  </div>
                </div>        
            </div>
            <p><?php echo $this->__('Please make sure the following fields are assigned correctly:');?></p>
            <div class="values-block">
               <table cellspacing="0" class="form-list">
                <tr class="t-header">
                    <td><strong><?php echo $this->__('Required Fields')?></strong></td><td><strong><?php echo $this->__('Detected field')?></strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('Title')?><span class="required">*</span></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[title]','title','name','required-entry chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('SKU')?><span class="required">*</span></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderSkuIdSelect('mapping_form[sku]','sku','sku','required-entry chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('UPC')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele">
                        <?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[upc]','upc','upc','chzn-select')?>

                    </td>
                    <td class="desc"><p><span><?php echo $this->__('Universal Product Code')?></span></p></td>                   
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('Brand')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[brand]','brand','brand','chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('Model')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[model]','model','model','chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('MPN')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[mpn]','mpn','mpn','chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('ASIN')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele">
                        <?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[asin]','asin','asin','chzn-select')?>

                    </td>
                    <td class="desc"><p><span><?php echo $this->__('Amazon Standard Identification Number')?></span></p></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('Price')?> <span class="required">*</span></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderPriceAttributesSelect('mapping_form[price]','price','price','required-entry chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('Cost')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[cost]','cost','0','chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label firstcol"><span><?php echo $this->__('Product image')?></span></td>
                    <td class="input-ele"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[productimage]','productimage','image','chzn-select')?></td>
                    <td></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr class="special-opt-cont">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="ship-price-cont minprice">
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-top">
                                <div class="label"><?php echo $this->__('MinPrice')?></div>
                                <div class="value"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[minprice]','minprice','cost','chzn-select')?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-mid"><span><?php echo $this->__('-Or-')?></span></div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-bott">
                               <div class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Set a minimum price:')?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-bott desc">
                              <p><span><?php echo $this->__('this will manually override the choosen attribute.')?></span></p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-bott">
                               <div class="label">
                                  <input id="minprice_man" type="text" name="mapping_form[minprice_man]"  value="<?php echo $this->getFixedMinPrice()?>"/> 
                                  <?php echo $this->renderMinPriceRuleSelects();?>
                               </div>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="desc"><p><span><?php echo $this->__('Wisepricer will never price below the minimum price you set.')?></span></p></td>                   
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div class="ship-price-cont">
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-top">
                                <div class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Shipping price')?></div>
                                <div class="value"><?php echo $this->renderAttributesSelect('mapping_form[shipping]','shipping','0','chzn-select')?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-mid"><span><?php echo $this->__('-Or-')?></span></div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-bott">
                               <div class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Enter fixed shipping price')?></div>
                               <div class="value"><input type="text" name="mapping_form[shipping_man]"  value="<?php echo $this->getShippingFixedRate()?>"/></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ship-price-cont-bott desc">
                              <p><span><?php echo $this->__('this will manually override the choosen attribute.')?></span></p>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </div>
      <div class="bott_block">
        <div class="bott_block_left"></div>
        <div class="bott_block_right">
          <button class="wp-save-btn" onclick="return beforeSubmit()"></button>
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </form>
<style>
  #wsp-mapping td{
    line-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 230px;
  }
  #wsp-mapping td.second-val{
      padding-left: 20px
  }
  #wsp-mapping{
      padding-top: 20px
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.observe('dom:loaded', function(evt) {
    var select, selects, _i, _len, _results;
    if (Prototype.Browser.IE && (Prototype.BrowserFeatures['Version'] === 6 || Prototype.BrowserFeatures['Version'] === 7)) {
      return;
    }
    selects = $$(".chzn-select");
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = selects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      select = selects[_i];
      _results.push(new Chosen(select,{disable_search_threshold: 50}));
    }
    deselects = $$(".chzn-select-deselect");
    for (_i = 0, _len = deselects.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      select = deselects[_i];
      _results.push(new Chosen(select,{allow_single_deselect:true}));
    }
    return _results;
  });

    var editForm = new varienForm('mapping_form');

    function beforeSubmit(){ 
      $('rule2').setStyle('border:none'); 
      $('rule1').setStyle('border:none');
      $('rule3').setStyle('border:none');
      var upc=$('upc').value;
      var brand=$('brand').value;
      var model=$('model').value;
      var asin=$('asin').value;
      var mpn=$('mpn').value;
      var minprice=$('minprice').value;
      var cost=$('cost').value;
      var minprice_man=$('minprice_man').value;

      var isValid=false;
      var failedRule=0;
      if(upc!=''||asin!=''){

            if(minprice!=''||(cost!=''&&minprice_man!='')){
                editForm.submit(); 
                return;
            }else{
               failedRule=3;   
            }
      }

      if((brand!=''&&model!='')||(brand!=''&&mpn!='')){

            if(minprice!=''||(cost!=''&&minprice_man!='')){
                editForm.submit(); 
                return;
            }else{
               failedRule=3;   
            }
      }

    if(failedRule==3){
        $('rule3').setStyle('border:red solid 1px');

    }else{
       $('rule2').setStyle('border:red solid 1px'); 
       $('rule1').setStyle('border:red solid 1px');
    }

      alert(Translator.translate('Please follow instructions in your mapping listed on the left.'));    
      window.location.hash='rule1';

      return false;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check your var/log folder for errors. Also you can add an `as` attribute on your block and remove the `output` attribute. `<block  type="syncer/adminhtml_mapping" template="wisepricer/mapping.phtml" name="wisepricer.mapping" as="mapping" />`. I didn't write this as an answer because I'm not sure it will work. I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: can we see more about the layout xml file, the block class, the template phtml file, the block's declaration in config.xml?

Comment: what does the `as` attribute do?